# Xpath result filtered by text in element

Tags: xml, xpath, nodes

I am trying to return xpath result based on a text in a element.

This is my current expression:
//S:Body/ns:2hentArsrapporterResponse/return/child::*[text()='2016']

however its only returning the the one element: Element='2016

The expression should return all of the elements in the return node if the  element contains text '2016'. Can someone please help me with the correct expression?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier here to just return all entire matching `<return>` nodes.  Since you want all children tags anyway, having an extra wrapper tag on the outside presumably would not be a problem, and it would also give you a better way of keeping your output organized.  Towards this end, we can just filter the `<return>` node directly:

```
//S:Body/ns:2hentArsrapporterResponse/return[antallVersjoner[text()='2016'] or ar[text()='2016'] or ...]
```

This solution obviously depends on listing out all possible children nodes which might match.  If you have many child nodes, this approach might not be optimal.

Comment: Thank you! It was just syntax that was wrong but: //S:Body/ns:2hentArsrapporterResponse/return[ar[text()='2016]] returned all the elements if the <ar> contained text '2016' :)

Comment: It's really best not to use `text()` here. Instead of `ar[text()='2016']`, use `ar[. = '2016']`, and instead of `*[ar/text()='2016']` use `*[ar = '2016']`. Using `text()` will fail if there are comments or mixed content present.